# Using frameset to divide screen into three parts in html

Tags: html

This may be a very basic question but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I need to split the page into three parts like 'T' so that I can load three Web pages using frameset and frames

Comment: [Like this?](http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/)

Comment: framesets are deprecated. use div with css to create the layout or use iframes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but any anyone give me a simple code to create the structure, because I am using my mobile phone to ask this question and can't access Internet through computer. I can't view the code from the suggested site correctly

Answer (score 0):

Frameset and frames were deprecated a LONG time ago.  Use CSS and divs for your layout.  I made a super basic JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3YAc/

Just using the CSS:

```
header { height:100px; background:red; text-align:center;}
#left,#right { float:left; width:50%; text-align:center; min-height:400px;}
#left { background:green;}
#right { background:blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a little bit css, so your css here:

```
.div1{
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 min-height: 500px
}
.div2{
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
 min-height: 500px
}
.div3{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5%;
 min-height: 500px
 width: 30%;
}
```

And here is your html:

```
<div class="div1"><!--your frame--></div>
<div class="div2"><!--your frame--></div>
<div class="div3"><!--your frame--></div>
```